# Setting auto-increment after filling table (Firebird) with existing data (from SQL Server)

Tags: sql, firebird, auto-increment, firebird-4.0

I have a table in SQL Server. Its PK, ID, is of type INT and is auto-incremented. The task I have is to get this table in a Firebird database (version 4.0.4). Remarks: we have a website that uses this DB where pages have a host of references to those IDs, so they should be kept as they are.

I'm using simple console program in .NET 6 (C#) to select and insert data using ADO.NET provider. My question is if I should first import data to the Firebird database and then add a generator as auto-increment to that table, considering the fact that generator should use the maximum value of PK of the existing data as its starting value. As far as I understand there at least two things to care about:

1. If I create auto-increment first and insert data (select without ID column), those IDs will start from 1.
2. I am not sure what will be the result of that generator's action when it starts from a default 0 value. Suppose there are IDs 2, 4, 5, 8. On next insert it creates 1 as ID. And what will be the outcome of the second one? ++1 gives 2 which is already in use, so we are stuck.

Am I on a correct way? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: After data copy set the generator to max value of copied id.

Comment: And in trigger (which is part of traditional Firebird AI system) don't override existing value in record to prevent IDs from changing during data pump.

Comment: What do you mean with _"it's strating value"_? Also, which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: In any case, with Firebird 4.0 or higher, use a [`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity-always) column, insert with [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-overriding), and alter the identity column afterwards to set the next value correctly (using `RESTART WITH`).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, saying 'starting value', I meant the first ID for incrementing. The Firebird version is 4.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use a sequence (a.k.a. generator) and not modify its current value after a bulk insert which inserts with explicit ID values, then for subsequent inserts, the sequence will generate values 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.. So, if such a value already happens to exist, you'll get duplicate values. What happens depends on whether or not the column has a primary key or unique key constraint: if there is no constraint, a duplicate ID value would be inserted, if there is a constraint, the insert will fail.

There are multiple ways to go about this. Since Firebird 3.0, Firebird has "real" [identity columns](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity), which means you don't have to fiddle with sequences and triggers yourself. The downside is that it is not possible to add an identity column to a table which already has rows, and it is not possible to convert an existing column to an identity column.

Given you're using Firebird 4.0, I would recommend doing the following:

1. Create the table with a [`GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity-always) column. You can also use [`GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity-default), but IMHO you should only do that if you want to be able to override the identity in general:

   ```sql
   create table YOUR_TABLE (
     ID integer generated always as identity constraint PK_YOUR_TABLE primary key,
     -- your other columns
   );
   ```
2. If you used `GENERATED ALWAYS` in the previous step, use the [`OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml-insert.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-overriding) in your `INSERT` statement. That way you can insert an explicit value into a *generated always* identity column.

   ```sql
   insert into YOUR_TABLE (ID, /* other columns */) overriding system value
     values (2, ...);
   ```

   If you used `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`, you don't need the `OVERRIDING` clause (allowing the insert to specify the identity column value is default behaviour for *generated by default*).
3. After inserting all rows, change the next value of the identity column to the current maximum + 1 (not to the current maximum!).

   - First obtain the maximum + 1 value:

     ```sql
     select 1 + max(ID) as NEXT_VALUE from YOUR_TABLE;
     ```

     Make sure you execute this while no other transactions insert records in this table.
   - Use the obtained value in [`ALTER TABLE .. RESTART WITH ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-altridentity), say `NEXT_VALUE` was 1923:

     ```
     alter table YOUR_TABLE alter column ID restart with 1923;
     ```
   - Alternatively, although formally not supported, you could use PSQL code to run this as one statement:

     ```
     set term #;
     execute block
     as
       declare NEXT_VALUE integer;
     begin
       select 1 + max(ID) from YOUR_TABLE into NEXT_VALUE;
       execute statement 'alter table YOUR_TABLE alter column ID restart with ' || NEXT_VALUE;
     end#
     set term ;#
     ```

     NOTE: Use of `SET TERM` is only needed for interactive execution, like when using ISQL. Firebird itself doesn't support this command. If you execute this, for example, from C#, you just need to execute the `execute block ... end` (without the `#`!).
4. From now on, insert records into this table without specifying the `ID` column (and if you do, and used *generated always* you'll get an error unless `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` has been specified).

If you insist on using sequences and triggers, you can do the following:

1. Create the table with a normal integer column:

   ```sql
   create table YOUR_TABLE_2 (
     ID integer constraint PK_YOUR_TABLE_2 primary key,
     -- your other columns
   );
   ```
2. Insert the rows:

   ```sql
   insert into YOUR_TABLE_2 (ID, /* other columns*/) values (2, ...);
   ```
3. After inserting the rows, define the sequence and auto-increment [trigger](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-trigger.html#fblangref40-ddl-trgr-create):

   - First obtain the next value:

     ```sql
     select 1 + max(ID) as NEXT_VALUE from YOUR_TABLE_2;
     ```
   - Then create the sequence and trigger (assume `NEXT_VALUE` was 1923):

     ```sql
     create sequence SEQ_YOUR_TABLE_2_ID start with 1923;
     set term #;
     create trigger GEN_ID_YOUR_TABLE_2 before insert on YOUR_TABLE_2
     as
     begin
       NEW.ID = next value for SEQ_YOUR_TABLE_2_ID;
     end#
     set term ;#
     ```

     NOTE: This trigger will unconditionally generate an ID. You may want to consider raising an exception if `NEW.ID` is not null, or to only generate an ID if `NEW.ID` is null. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956111/466862) for a conditional alternative.

     Although you could use the PSQL trick to set the sequence value dynamically, I would recommend to first create the sequence (leave off the `START WITH` clause) and trigger, commit the transaction, and then use an `EXECUTE BLOCK` with [`ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART WITH ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-sequence.html#fblangref40-ddl-sequence-alter) if you want to go that route.

Comment: I appreciate such kinds of explanations when you get the exhaustive answer to your question. I also read the link you provided me about race condition in context of a new ID generating. The only thing I would like to shed more light on is you reccomendation in the last paragraph of the reply. What are the its benefits over the last code sample?

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov Which part specifically, about using the PSQL trick, or making the trigger conditional on NEW.ID being null or not?

Comment: To tell the truth, both of those points: why leaving off the `start with` clause and using `alter sequence` after it is more preferable than each way as they are + Although I've been using firebird CRUD operations for while and moreover I've written a few procedures (even though, IBExpert takes responsibility for managing procedures, triggers and generators creation and you write only the executing block part), when is `NEW.ID IS NULL` true?

Comment: It is not preferable, but if you use the PSQL trick you probably need to (though I haven't double checked) The problem is that using `EXECUTE STATEMENT` to execute DDL is a hack, and can have visibility issues, so if (and only if) you're using that hack, you should do it in a separate transaction from the transaction that created the object.

Comment: As to the second part, `NEW.ID` will be `NULL` in the trigger when you don't include it in your insert, e.g. your use `INSERT YOUR_TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) values (..., ...)`, and that can be used to decide if you want or need to generate a value.