# How to return a newly generated ID from a stored procedure in Firebird

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird-psql

I have a procedure which inserts record into a table. I also have a trigger which auto-increments sequence on `BEFORE INSERT` (also there is identity type). I'd like to operate with its result, e.g. highlight a new record in a table on a website for example. Is usage of `RETURNS` with `GEN_ID(<sequence>, 0)` the only way? If so, there is a race condition, as far as I know, isn't it? My ID may not be mine if someone's transaction succeeds first.

There is also a `RETURNING` clause, but as far as I know it could be used in DML queries like in execute block or dynamic statements as in `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING ID`?

Comment: Please show your stored procedure code. If you use [`insert`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert) in your stored procedures, it is as simple as declaring a returns parameter of appropriate type, and using `insert into ... returning id into :a_return_parameter;`. As an aside, if you're using a recent version of Firebird, consider using an identity column instead of a trigger to generate the new id.

Comment: See also the third example in [The `RETURNING` Clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-returning), or [the first example for `create procedure`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#create-procedure-examples)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thank you for taking my attention to identity column. I refactored my DB  in accordance with the new features. By the way, I used your answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764223/setting-auto-increment-after-filling-table-firebird-with-existing-data-from-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return a generated id from a stored procedure, all you have to do is use the [`RETURNING` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert-returning) in your [`INSERT` statement](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-insert), and assign it to one of the output variables of the stored procedure.

As a simple example:

```sql
create table example_table (
  id integer generated by default as identity constraint pk_example_table primary key,
  val varchar(50)
);

set term #;
create procedure add_to_example(new_val type of column example_table.val) 
  returns (new_id type of column example_table.id)
as
begin
  insert into example_table (val) values (:new_val) returning id into new_id;
end#
set term ;#
```

You can then execute this as:

```sql
execute procedure add_to_example('abc');
```

For example:

```
SQL> execute procedure add_to_example('abc');

      NEW_ID
============
           1

SQL> execute procedure add_to_example('bce');

      NEW_ID
============
           2

SQL>
```

Comment: I'm greatful for your code. I used to think of `RETURNING` as a  tool when you insert not by means of procedure (as if `RETURNING` cannot be combined with `RETURNS` and output parameters).

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov That is because you're conflating two separate things: 1) returning values from the insert to the caller (in this case the stored procedure), and 2) returning values from the stored procedure to its caller (e.g. you, or another stored procedure).